# Good value for the ratio_skew_across_slices [REDSHIFT]

Tags: database, performance, amazon-redshift

I read this article:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_analyzing-table-design.html

It gives a query to analyze table design. For each table it gives two indicator:

- ratio_skew_across_slices
- pct_slices_populated

In the article I read that a small value is good for the ratio_skew_across_slices. How small must it be? I found only this article that gives me a threshold:

https://dwgeek.com/redshift-table-data-skew-avoid.html/

< 4 is good. Can I accept this threshold? I have some tables with the values of 2.0 and 2.15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, there is no acceptable or defined value for the table skew. But the thumb rule is to keep it less than 4.

To understand this, let's see an example.

You have a table with 150 rows and the cluster has 3 nodes.

- Node 1 - 100 rows
- Node 2 - 48 rows
- Node 3 - 2 rows

How the skew is calculated?

The ratio between the max rows on a node and the least rows on a node.

`100/2 = 50. So the skew here is 50.`

But its a very small table, even though the skew is high, there is no impact, but think about a large table.

- Node 1 - 50000000
- Node 2 - 30000000
- Node 3 - 40000000

`Skew is 1.67`

Here the skew is very small but the impact is too high while scanning your data.

So it's up to you to decide for a particular table is this skew fine or needs to be optimized.